# When getting multiple activities and their reactions, is there a way to get reactions oldest to newest?

Tags: getstream-io

When retrieving more than one activity and their reactions the default order of a set of reactions (per the documentation below) is newest to oldest but I'd like to retrieve them oldest to newest, is there a way to do this?

https://getstream.io/docs/python/#reactions_retrieve-reactions

I've been working on getting reactions oldest to newest for just one activity when paginating, however now I'm realizing I still need this to work for when I retrieve reactions for more than one activity. I tried putting "id_gt" as mentioned in the documentation in a few spots in the code but so far I have not had success. The problem with that idea is I'm not passing an id at this point, it's a high level call. This is why I thought a parameter called something like "date" and an option to order ascending or descending made more sense as an implementation. I'm assuming if this is currently possible something would have to go into the "reaction={}" block to order them there?

```py
response = feed.get(limit=10, enrich=True, reactions={"counts": True, "recent": True})
```

So in conclusion I'd just expect the part of the method that gets reactions for multiple activities to accept a parameter that would allow me to order them oldest to newest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported by the APIs; changing the order is only allowed when you paginate reactions for one activity or user.

Comment: I understand well thank you for responding. If it's something that isn't too complicated to do I'd certainly like the option to do so. If in the future this can be tagged to be updated I'd be grateful to know when it is.